# How to make a value interact with lines within its range on a table column?

Tags: c#, variables, datatable

I have a datatable, like this.

[image]

At some point people will be required to provide their own measurement, which can be -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 etc... all up till 35.

I need to make an interpolation between the resulting values of the measurement.

I could do something like this

```
double usermeasurement;
//user inserts the measurement in a textbox

if(usermeasurement <5)
{ //interpolation between line 1 and line 2 of the table
}

else if (usermeasurement <15)
{ //interpolation between line 2 and 3 of the table..
} 
// and so on...
```

My programming question is, is there a simpler, advanced way to make the `usermeasurement` variable fit itself on the column `measurement`?

I can make my own interpolation method, but is there a simpler math operation that does it?

Comment: Do you want to fetch this directly from a table in the database or from a DataTable in code?

Comment: @PraveenPaulose I've no idea, it's the first time i'm trying a not so dumb approach. Whatever is simpler and easier to understand i guess, I couldn't find useful information about fetching, unlike querying, I guess i'd rather Query, unless you don't recommend it. I have like 5 intervals but on a lot of different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fetching this from a DataTable in code

```
int userInput = 7;

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Measurement", typeof(int)));
dataTable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Value", typeof(string)));

dataTable.Rows.Add(-5, "-0,1");
dataTable.Rows.Add(5, "0,2");
dataTable.Rows.Add(15, "0,5");
dataTable.Rows.Add(25, "0,7");
dataTable.Rows.Add(35, "0,9");

int min = Convert.ToInt32(dataTable.Compute("MIN(Measurement)", "Measurement > " + userInput.ToString()));
int max = Convert.ToInt32(dataTable.Compute("MAX(Measurement)", "Measurement < " + userInput.ToString()));
DataRow[] rows = dataTable.Select("Measurement = " + min.ToString() + " OR " + "Measurement = " + max.ToString());
```

If you are querying your database then use the below query

```
SELECT * FROM Measurements WHERE Measurement = (select MIN(Measurement) from Measurements WHERE Measurement > 16) OR Measurement = (select MAX(Measurement) from Measurements WHERE Measurement < 16)
```

Comment: Wow very informative, i've heard of query and fetching before and had no idea that it was meant to access tables. What exactly do you mean by SELECT, FROM, WHERE, etc? Can you detail it some more? I also noticed that you defined Value as a string , and Measurement as a int, is that a requirement for fetching? @Praveen Paulose

Comment: This is SQL (Structured Query Language), a language used to manage relational databases. This is an exhaustive subject and you can find information on this topic all over the Internet. I assumed Value as string, since your samples had a comma in it. It can be any data type you wish. I hope this answers your queries.

Comment: unfortunately no, I've come up with a `dataselect` command, it creates an array and works pretty nicely, but i don't think it accepts variables as a search term, since it searches trough a string, i will update my question. Thank you anyways

Comment: The first section of my answer details how you can achieve the same results with a dataselect command. Wouldn't that be that the answer then?

Comment: I'm very sorry, didn't give it a closer look since i found a lot more information about query commands, and i've been sleep deprived for  nearly 20 hours :P Once again, sorry about that, you'r completely right. Thanks for reminding me